# C - Вывести на экран из файла строки длиной больше 60 символов

Tags: c, массивы, строки, файлы, динамические-массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 255

void main()
{
    char mem[N];
    FILE * fil;
    int temp, k, length = 60;
    fil = fopen("D:\\FilesProjects\\1file.txt", "rt");
    while (fgets(mem,N,fil)!=NULL) 
    {
        if (strlen(mem) >= 60) printf("%s \n", mem);

    }
    fclose(fil);
    system("pause");
}
```

Возможно ли переделать данный код так, чтобы он выводил на экран строки из файла определенной длины БЕЗ использования массивов или строк? Очень надо.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Вам нужно уметь находить и запоминать границы строк, где левая граница - начало файла или <позиция последнего перевода строки + 1>, а правая - позиция следующего перевода строки. То есть запоминаете позицию начала строки, считываете символы и считаете их количество с помощью `getchar()` до тех пор, пока не встретите перевод строки или конец файла, затем, если количество считанных символов подходит под условие для вывода строки, то с помощью `fseek` переводите курсор чтения файла на запомненную ранее позицию начала строки, опять читаете посредством `getchar()` символы и сразу же выводите их до конца строки. Повторяете для каждой строки, не забывая сбрасывать счетчик посчитанных символов в строке.

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
long cur = 0;

while (fgets(mem,N,fil) !=NULL) 
{
    long next = fseek(fil, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    if ((next - cur) > 60)
       fputs(mem,fil);

    cur = next;

}
fputc('\n',fil);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже сделал